# How might I construct a non-default constructor model from a query string in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding, api-design, optional-parameters, constructor-overloading

**I would like to construct an object that has a non-default constructor from query string parameters in ASP.Net Core.** In essence, I have two models that have a common ancestor class with different parameterizations. Based on some conditions in an API endpoint, one model will be constructed with parameters from the query string.

```cs
[HttpGet("{model}")]
public ModelBase Get(string model)
{
  switch (model)
  {
    case "foo":
      ModelFoo foo = GetModelFromQueryString<ModelFoo>();
      return foo;
    case "bar":
      ModelBar bar = GetModelFromQueryString<ModelBar>();
      return bar;
  }
  return null;
}
```

`GetModelFromQueryString<TModel>` is obviously the magical function that I wish I knew existed. If it already exists or someone could help provide implementation details, that would answer my question.

The example model classes would be like the following:

```cs
class ModelFoo : ModelBase
{
  public ModelFoo(int param1=1, int param2=2)
  {
    // ...
  }
}

class ModelBar : ModelBase
{
  public ModelBar(int paramBaz=3)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This would ideally make the following HTTP calls yield the desired results:

- `GET api/foo?param1=7&param2=9` yields `new ModelFoo(param1:7, param2:9)`.
- `GET api/bar?paramBaz=42` yields `new ModelBar(paramBaz:42)`.
- `GET api/foo` yields `new ModelFoo(param1:1, param2:2)`.
- `GET api/foo?param2=11` yields `new ModelFoo(param1:1, param2:11)`.

How might I go about this? Should I restructure entirely?

I realize that this may be a bit of a complicated, multi-faceted question so any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use my working demo.

Class:

```
public class ModelBase
{
     
}

class ModelFoo : ModelBase
{
    public int param1 { get; set; }
    public int param2 { get; set; }
    public ModelFoo(int param1 = 1, int param2 = 2)
    {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }
}

class ModelBar : ModelBase
{
    public int paramBaz { get; set; }
    public ModelBar(int paramBaz = 3)
    {
        this.paramBaz = paramBaz;
    }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet("{model}")]
    public ModelBase Get(string model,int param1,int param2,int paramBaz)
    {
        switch (model)
        {
            case "foo":
                if(param1!=0 ^ param2!=0)
                {
                    if(param1 != 0)
                    {
                        ModelFoo foo1 = new ModelFoo
                        {
                            param1 = param1,
                        };
                        return foo1;
                    }
                    if (param2 != 0)
                    {
                        ModelFoo foo2 = new ModelFoo
                        {
                            param2 = param2,
                        };
                        return foo2;
                    }

                }
                if (param1 == 0 && param2 == 0)
                {
                    ModelFoo foo3 = new ModelFoo();
                   
                    return foo3;
                }
                ModelFoo foo4 = new ModelFoo
                {
                    param1 = param1,
                    param2 = param2,
                };
                return foo4;


            case "bar":
                if (paramBaz != 0)
                {
                    ModelBar bar = new ModelBar
                    {
                        paramBaz = paramBaz,

                    };
                    return bar;
                }
                ModelBar bar1 = new ModelBar();
                return bar1;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer to your question, but the needed building blocks are already available.

Newtonsoft JSON.net supports creating types if the constructor parameter matches the property names and also supports creating instances of an interface if the concrete type is set within a `$type` property:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sourceList = new List<IModel> { new ModelFoo(3, 7), new ModelBar(11) };
        var jsonList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sourceList, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IModel>>(jsonList, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });

        return 0;
    }
}

public interface IModel { }

public class ModelFoo : IModel
{
    public ModelFoo(int first, int second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
    public int First { get; }
    public int Second { get; }
}

public class ModelBar : IModel
{
    public ModelBar(int third)
    {
        Third = third;
    }

    public int Third { get; }
}
```